# Is there any way through which i can store array data in variable using java and use that variable further

Tags: java, excel

I am currently working on importing excel sheet data, storing that data row wise in an array.My goal is to store each cell data in a uniquely defined variable and use the same variable further for a single iteration simultaneously save data of next row in the same variable and reuse.can anyone please help me in this issue(please explain with an example just to understand) 
this is how the code is

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws NullPointerException {

    try {
        File fXmlFile = new File("bin/testngscript/v1.xml");
        //get the factory
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        //Using factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
        Document doc = db.parse(fXmlFile);
        //read the xml node element
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Excelpath");
        String excelpath1 =null;
        for (int index = 0; index < nodeList.getLength(); index++) {
        System.out.println(nodeList.item(index).getTextContent());
         excelpath1= nodeList.item(index).getTextContent();
         System.out.println(excelpath1);
    }
         excelpath2= excelpath1;
        System.out.println(excelpath2);
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    int rownum = 0;

                String Filepath = excelpath2;
         FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Filepath); 
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            HSSFWorkbook hw = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
             HSSFSheet sheet = hw.getSheetAt(0); 
                  rownum= sheet.getLastRowNum(); 
    Object[][] product_data=new Object[rownum][14];


    try {

                  System.out.println("excelpath is"+excelpath2);      

    for(int i=1;i<rownum;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<14;){
            product_data[i][j]="productname";
            product_data[i][j++]="url";
            product_data[i][j++]="themename";
            product_data[i][j++]="papertype";
            product_data[i][j++]="paperfinish";
            product_data[i][j++]="packaging";
            product_data[i][j++]="noofpages";
            product_data[i][j++]="expectedprice";
            product_data[i][j++]="priceinkart";
            product_data[i][j++]="shippingcharges";
            product_data[i][j++]="taxexpected";
            product_data[i][j++]="taxactual";
            product_data[i][j++]="total";
            product_data[i][j++]="totalexpected";
            System.out.println(product_data[i][j++]);
            j=0;
        }
    }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see an issue, just an assignment. What is the actual question?

Comment: Well, yeah, after you "store array data in variable", you go on and "use that variable further" down in the code. If that code is in functions you call, you pass the array as parameters. You can also store the array in a field and use it elsewhere in the class after that.

Comment: can you please explain it with an example,just for my understanding purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an indirect answer, use java reflection take data from xls which is more easy to do.
Take examples from testng or selenium where they do several thing in same way

Example
[A library that can fill Java object with data declared in Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704123/a-library-that-can-fill-java-object-with-data-declared-in-excel-file)
http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/2010/02/excel-read-writable-reports-through-generics-reflection-and-apache-poi/

Still good examples in github

Comment: can u please share me the link if possible

Comment: adding example in the post